# Pairing elements in a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a list of lists like this.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [3, 2, 0.3]
c = [0.1, 3, 6.8]
d = [9, 2.5, 7, 2]

x = [a, b, c, d]
```

I want to pair them like this:

```
[a, b], [b, a], [a, c], [c, a], [a, d], [d, a], [b, c], [c, b], [b, d], [d, b], [c, d], [d, c]
```

This is the way I do it:

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x):
         if i!= j:
             #TODO...
             print(x[i], x[j])
```

My question is: Is there a smarter way to do it to improve performance? ( When x has 6-7 items, I can tell it slowing down a lot).

Any of your inputs would help me a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46150179/paring-lists-of-a-list-of-list-in-python#comment79262112_46150242) gave me an interesting idea. Here it is, using *`itertools.combinations`*, which returns items in the order you're looking for.

```
from itertools import combinations

def foo(x):
     for x in combinations(x, 2):
         yield from (x, x[::-1]) # python3.3+ 


for i in foo(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']):
    print(i)

('a', 'b')
('b', 'a')
('a', 'c')
('c', 'a')
('a', 'd')
('d', 'a')
('b', 'c')
('c', 'b')
('b', 'd')
('d', 'b')
('c', 'd')
('d', 'c')
```

Replace `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']` with `[a, b, c, d]`, which is your actual list of lists.

---

*Note:* On python <3.3, you'd need `yield x; yield x[::-1]`, because `yield from` isn't supported.

Comment: @COLDSPEED I find you solution is really easy to read and fits my need. Thanks

Comment: @ryanvolap Happy to help. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [3, 2, 0.3]
c = [0.1, 3, 6.8]
d = [9, 2.5, 7, 2]
x = [a, b, c, d]
import itertools
list(itertools.permutations(x, 2))
[([1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 0.3]), ([1, 2, 3, 4], [0.1, 3, 6.8]), ([1, 2, 3, 4], [9, 2.5, 7, 2]), ([3, 2, 0.3], [1, 2, 3, 4]), ([3, 2, 0.3], [0.1, 3, 6.8]), ([3, 2, 0.3], [9, 2.5, 7, 2]), ([0.1, 3, 6.8], [1, 2, 3, 4]), ([0.1, 3, 6.8], [3, 2, 0.3]), ([0.1, 3, 6.8], [9, 2.5, 7, 2]), ([9, 2.5, 7, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]), ([9, 2.5, 7, 2], [3, 2, 0.3]), ([9, 2.5, 7, 2], [0.1, 3, 6.8])]
```

As comment say, for the specific order you can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: (x, x[::-1]), 
                                       itertools.combinations(x, 2))))
[([1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 2, 0.3]), ([3, 2, 0.3], [1, 2, 3, 4]), ([1, 2, 3, 4], [0.1, 3, 6.8]), ([0.1, 3, 6.8], [1, 2, 3, 4]), ([1, 2, 3, 4], [9, 2.5, 7, 2]), ([9, 2.5, 7, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4]), ([3, 2, 0.3], [0.1, 3, 6.8]), ([0.1, 3, 6.8], [3, 2, 0.3]), ([3, 2, 0.3], [9, 2.5, 7, 2]), ([9, 2.5, 7, 2], [3, 2, 0.3]), ([0.1, 3, 6.8], [9, 2.5, 7, 2]), ([9, 2.5, 7, 2], [0.1, 3, 6.8])]
```

Comment: If you want to get the order as specified by the OP, it might be easiest to use a `combinations`-based approach with each combo forward and backward.

Comment: Do you mind removing the combinations approach? That's the same as my answer.

Comment: it is not exactly the same, will you expand yours?

Comment: I don't think so? Sacrificing readability to fit it in one line isn't a great idea.

Comment: the idea is not fit it in one line, it is use `itertools`

Comment: You asked me if I'd expand on my answer... I don't see the need to?

Comment: i dont see the need to remove mine, Is there a problem? i cant see it, but if it bothers you I would remove it... :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154111/discussion-between-daniel-sanchez-and-cs).

Answer (score 0):

you can try `zip`:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = [7,8,9]
x = [a,b,c]
y = []
for i in range (0,len(x)):
    for j in range (i + 1, len(x)):
        y.append(zip(x[i],x[j]))
        y.append(zip(x[j],x[i]))
print y
```

Comment: Why `.__len__` and not `len()`?

Comment: `x.__len__()`? use `len(x)` better